# How can I extract some lines from a string while adding parentheses to the resulting string where I need it?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a python string which contains the output of a Metric-FF planner that looks like this:

```
ff: parsing domain file
domain 'BRILLOPROVA' defined
 ... done.
ff: parsing problem file
problem 'TASK' defined
 ... done.


translating negated cond for predicate DIRTY-BLENDER
translating negated cond for predicate EMPTY-BLENDER
no metric specified.

ff: search configuration is Enforced Hill-Climbing, if that fails then best-first search.
Metric is plan length.
NO COST MINIMIZATION (and no cost-minimizing relaxed plans).

Cueing down from goal distance:    6 into depth [1]
                                   5            [1][2][3]
                                   4            [1]
                                   3            [1]
                                   2            [1]
                                   1            [1]
                                   0            

ff: found legal plan as follows
step    0: PICK-UP-GLASS H
        1: PICK-FLAVOR H PAPAYA VASCHETTA
        2: ADD-JUICE MELA H PAPAYA VASCHETTA
        3: BLEND MELA PAPAYA H
        4: TRASH-CUP VASCHETTA H
        5: FILL-GLASS H
        6: WASH-BLENDER
        7: SERVE LEFT

time spent:    0.00 seconds instantiating 10 easy, 0 hard action templates
               0.00 seconds reachability analysis, yielding 14 facts and 10 actions
               0.00 seconds creating final representation with 14 relevant facts, 0 relevant fluents
               0.00 seconds computing LNF
               0.00 seconds building connectivity graph
               0.00 seconds searching, evaluating 12 states, to a max depth of 3
               0.00 seconds total time
```

and I need to parse it so that the resulting string looks like this:

```
PICK-UP-GLASS PICK-FLAVOR(PAPAYA) ADD-JUICE BLEND TRASH-CUP FILL-GLASS WASH-BLENDER SERVE(LEFT)
```

So I need only the sequence of the actions, keeping only some parameters for the actions "PICK-FLAVOR" (precisely it will be the name of a fruit), and "SERVE" (which can have only "LEFT", "RIGHT" and "CENTER" as a parameter).
Keeping in mind that words like the parameters "VASCHETTA" and "H" and the names of the actions ("PICK-UP-GLASS", "PICK-FLAVOR", "ADD-JUICE", "BLEND", "TRASH-CUP", "FILL-GLASS", "WASH-BLENDER", "SERVE") are already known to me, so I can get rid of them easily with regex, but words like "MELA", "PAPAYA" and "LEFT" can vary witch each output, so I don't know them in advance and can't seem to manipulate the string to get the result I want.

I've tried the following code to trim the string at the best of my abilities:

```
import re
string = """
ff: parsing domain file
domain 'BRILLOPROVA' defined
 ... done.
ff: parsing problem file
problem 'TASK' defined
 ... done.


translating negated cond for predicate DIRTY-BLENDER
translating negated cond for predicate EMPTY-BLENDER
no metric specified.

ff: search configuration is Enforced Hill-Climbing, if that fails then best-first search.
Metric is plan length.
NO COST MINIMIZATION (and no cost-minimizing relaxed plans).

Cueing down from goal distance:    6 into depth [1]
                                   5            [1][2][3]
                                   4            [1]
                                   3            [1]
                                   2            [1]
                                   1            [1]
                                   0            

ff: found legal plan as follows
step    0: PICK-UP-GLASS H
        1: PICK-FLAVOR H PAPAYA VASCHETTA
        2: ADD-JUICE MELA H PAPAYA VASCHETTA
        3: BLEND MELA PAPAYA H
        4: TRASH-CUP VASCHETTA H
        5: FILL-GLASS H
        6: WASH-BLENDER
        7: SERVE LEFT

time spent:    0.00 seconds instantiating 10 easy, 0 hard action templates
               0.00 seconds reachability analysis, yielding 14 facts and 10 actions
               0.00 seconds creating final representation with 14 relevant facts, 0 relevant fluents
               0.00 seconds computing LNF
               0.00 seconds building connectivity graph
               0.00 seconds searching, evaluating 12 states, to a max depth of 3
               0.00 seconds total time
"""
list = string.split("""ff: found legal plan as follows
step""")
list = list[1].split("time spent:")
steps = list[0]
steps = steps.translate({ord(i): None for i in '0123456789:'})
steps = re.sub("\s+H\s+", " ", steps)
steps = re.sub("\s+VASCHETTA\s+", " ", steps)
steps = re.sub("ADD-JUICE .* BLEND", "ADD-JUICE BLEND", steps)
steps = re.sub("BLEND [A-Z]* [A-Z]* " ,"BLEND " , steps)
list = steps.split("PICK-FLAVOR ")
steps = list[0] + "PICK-FLAVOR(" + list[1]
print(steps)
```

with this result:

```
 PICK-UP-GLASS PICK-FLAVOR(PAPAYA ADD-JUICE BLEND TRASH-CUP FILL-GLASS WASH-BLENDER
     SERVE LEFT
```

So I'm almost there, but I don't know how to add the rest of the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `finditer` to find the words that interest you. The regex pattern could roughly be organised like this (pseudo code):

```
\d+: (actions|actions-with-param skip-word* param)
```

The real thing is a bit longer, as it names each action word and each word to skip, adding capture groups for what needs to be retained:

```
res = re.finditer(r"\d+:\s(?:(PICK-UP-GLASS|ADD-JUICE|BLEND|TRASH-CUP|FILL-GLASS|WASH-BLENDER)\b|(PICK-FLAVOR|SERVE) (?:(?:H|VASHETTA)\s)*(\w+))", string)

result = "\n".join(m.group(1) or (m.group(2) + "(" + m.group(3) + ")") for m in res)

print(result)
```